# Run Java 6 file on Java 7 (or 32 bit file...)

Tags: java

i tryed to run .jar file on lasted Java 7. I received this error:

```
Could not load 'plugins/ucars.jar' in folder 'plugins'
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/useful/ucars/ucars : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:184)
at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:305)
at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:230)
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_4_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:239)
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_4_R1.CraftServer.<init>(CraftServer.java:217)
at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_R1.PlayerList.<init>(PlayerList.java:55)
at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_R1.DedicatedPlayerList.<init>(SourceFile:11)
at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:104)
at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:399)
at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_R1.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:849)
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/useful/ucars/ucars : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass0(PluginClassLoader.java:80)
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:53)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:173)
... 9 more
```

(This is [CraftBukkit](http://bukkit.org/) v1.4.7 R1.0 server)
Only this plugin, .jar, not working.

If this is because java version not the same, how can i run Java 6 file (?) on Java 7 ?

(Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5)

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely vice versa. You are trying run java program which where compiled for `Java 7` (`major.minor version 51.0`) under `Java 6`.
Check, which version of `JRE` you use.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that you are trying to use a class that was compiled with JDK 7, on a Java 6 runtime environment (not the other way around!).

Java is backwards compatible. Newer versions of Java can use classes compiled with older versions of Java without modification.

Make sure that you are using Java 7 to run your class. You can check your Java runtime environment and JDK versions with:

```
java -version
javac -version
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the software-vendor do rebuild their products to be compatible with Java 6, or you could run Java 7 instead. Because Java 6 is EOL - means that it reached End of Lifetime, and because Java 6 will get not one more public update even if more new bugs are found as there where found the latest weeks, you should install Java 7.